# assigning boundary values to a weakly differentiable function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

There is a sentence in Evans I cannot justify.[image]

The claim made is $u=g$ on $\partial U$ in the trace sense.
Why? I understand that $u\in H^1$ implies $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$. But we also need the assumption $u\in C(\bar{U})$ to conclude $u=g$ on $\partial U$ in the trace sense, right? But there is no where in the book this is specified.

Hope someone can clarify. This is on p.315.

Comment: You do not need that $u \in C(\overline U)$. That $u = g$ on $\partial U$ in the trace sense mean that $Tu =g$, where $T : W^{1,2}(U) \to L^2(\partial U)$ is the trace operator.

Comment: OK. So the fact $u$ has value on the boundary, i.e. $u=g$ on the boundary already implies $u\in W^{1,p}(U)\cap C(\bar{U})$, right?

Comment: No. (Why do you think that is true?)

Comment: I am reading the trace theorem in Evans...well, my understanding is that, if $Tu=u=g$ holds only if $u\in W{1,p}(U)\cap C(\bar{U})$. So I think $u$ must in $C(\bar{U})$. Why not?

Comment: The trace operator is first defined on $u\in C^1(\overline U)$, and then it is shown that $\|u|_{\partial U}||_{L^p(\partial U)} \le C \| u\|_{W^{1,p}(U)}$. This implies that the mapping $u\to u|_{\partial U}$ defined on $C^1(\overline U)$ has a unique extension to $T: W^{1,p}(U)\to L(\partial U)$. So $T$ is defined on $W^{1,p}(U)$.

Comment: I cannot understand your first sentence, how do I know the trace operator is first defined on $u\in C^1(\bar{U})$?

Comment: Also, I cannot see the inequality (the 2nd part of your first sentence). Is this from one of those sobolev inequality in Chapt5?

Comment: I am following Evans. Please see p.272 (second edition) on the definition of $T$.